# Вопрос про динамический тип в C++

Tags: c++, c

Меня интересует следующий вопрос.

В языке `C` есть понятие `эффективного типа`. Это понятие обозначает тип объекта, который где-либо размещен.

Например:

```
int i = 1;
float f = 2;
// sizeof(int) == sizeof(float)
// Допустим, что эти типы также имеют одинаковые требования к выравниванию.    

void* data = malloc(4); // В данный момент объект (или память), на который указывает data, не имеет эффективного типа.

memcpy(data, &i, sizeof(int));// Теперь объект (или память), на который указывает data, имеет эффективный тип int.

float* pf1 = data;// Предположительно, возникновение неопределенного поведения, эффективные типы не совпадают.
*f1 = 3.14f;// Гарантированное возникновение неопределенного поведения, эффективные типы не совпадают.

memcpy(data, &f, sizeof(float);// data меняет эффективный тип с int на float.
float *pf2 = data;// Позволено.
*pf2 = 3.1415.f;// Позволено.
```

Насколько мне известно, в языке `C++` нет понятия `эффективного типа`, но есть понятие `динамического типа`. Скажите, пожалуйста, действительно ли `Стандарт` требует размещения `New` или `Placement New` для того, чтобы можно было безопасно работать с бестиповым участком памяти, который, например, был получен из `malloc()`?

Comment: Копирование через байтовый буфер как раз не должно вызывать UB. Вы может быть путаете с type punning через union?

Comment: @0andriy, нет, я имею в виду, что в языке `C` эффективный тип объекта, расположенного в бестиповом участке памяти, меняется записью.

Comment: Бред какой-то. Вы выделили память в 4 байта, никакого типа это не имеет. Копировать туда можно что угодно и делать type aliasing, лишь бы выхода за пределы не было. Ну и да, выравнивание по адресам, но это как правило менеджер памяти делает автоматически. Это из книжки или откуда?

Comment: @0andriy, судя по всему, `Стандарт C++` считает иначе.

Comment: @MGNeo, можно ссылку? впервые за 10 лет слышу понятие "эффективного типа"

Comment: Эффективный тип присутствует в `C`: https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/object#Effective_type
Динамический тип присутствует в `C++`:
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/type#Dynamic_type

Comment: В Cи здесь нет ни какого UB... если говорить в терминах стандарта, эффективный тип меняется любым сохранением в аллоцированный (не имеющий объявленного типа) объект, не важно через присваивание или через `memcpy`... приведение void* к float* — тоже абсолютно легальное...

Comment: @Fat-Zer, а что значит "меняется"? где он меняется, кусок памяти в 4 байта так и остается кусокм памяти в 4 байта, если кто-то туда записал 1 байт чар, то как узнать, что там теперь "эффективный" чар?

Comment: @goldstar_labs, компилятор видит код и определяет эффективный тип объекта. Точно так же он определяет действующий член объединения.

Comment: @goldstar_labs, эффективный тип — это нудная концепция языка, а не что-то существующее реально... она может явно присутствовать где-то в недрах компилятора, но это не обязательно... это просто промежуточный термин, который используется только на паре страниц из всего стандарта, чтобы определить порядок пресловутого «strict aliasing»'а... так что под «меняется» (в стандарте *становится*, *becomes*), подразумевается то, что после копирования в эти 4 байта `float` к объекту по этому адресу уже нельзя обращаться как к `int` — это будет некорректной с точки зрения языка, а следовательно `UB`.

Comment: @Fat-Zer, спасибо)

Comment: @Fat-Zer, не очень понял из ваших комментариев, можно ли в C++ делать так: `void* p = malloc(sizeof(int)); *static_cast<int*>(p) = 1;`?

Comment: @wololo, конечно, можно... иначе `malloc` вообще не имел бы смысла...

Comment: Но если вместо `int` (который POD) подставить тип с конструктором, то нельзя. Для C++ экземпляры не-POD типов возникают только после конструирования. Для чего вам будет нужен placement `new`.